# Node.js always gives errors when using -g flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Whenever I try installing something with node globally, I get a bunch of errors. I just tried it in Powershell and it didn't throw any errors, but that might be because it's Powershell and not the official Node command line application that's installed. I tried Powershell because I thought I might be able to copy and paste the errors, but I can't/they didn't appear. I tried again in the official Node console, and got the errors again. There's a screenshot of the errors at the bottom.

Here's the npm-debug.log file that was generated when I tried `npm install learnyounode -g`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Tierney\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'learnyounode',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.4
3 info using node@v0.10.26
4 verbose cache add [ 'learnyounode', null ]
5 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="learnyounode" args=["learnyounode",null]
6 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
6 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
6 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
6 verbose parsed url   host: null,
6 verbose parsed url   port: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
6 verbose parsed url   search: null,
6 verbose parsed url   query: null,
6 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'learnyounode',
6 verbose parsed url   path: 'learnyounode',
6 verbose parsed url   href: 'learnyounode' }
7 silly lockFile 8d456d9f-learnyounode learnyounode
8 verbose lock learnyounode C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\8d456d9f-learnyounode.lock
9 silly lockFile 8d456d9f-learnyounode learnyounode
10 silly lockFile 8d456d9f-learnyounode learnyounode
11 verbose addNamed [ 'learnyounode', '' ]
12 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
13 silly lockFile a353de34-learnyounode learnyounode@
14 verbose lock learnyounode@ C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\a353de34-learnyounode.lock
15 silly addNameRange { name: 'learnyounode', range: '*', hasData: false }
16 verbose url raw learnyounode
17 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './learnyounode' ]
18 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/learnyounode
19 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 17:41:57
20 verbose etag "BOCKXHU6AMIWDF78HOHVQMZBJ"
21 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/learnyounode
22 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/learnyounode
23 silly registry.get cb [ 304,
23 silly registry.get   { date: 'Mon, 24 Mar 2014 21:42:04 GMT',
23 silly registry.get     server: 'Apache',
23 silly registry.get     via: '1.1 varnish',
23 silly registry.get     'last-modified': 'Mon, 24 Mar 2014 21:42:04 GMT',
23 silly registry.get     'cache-control': 'max-age=1',
23 silly registry.get     etag: '"BOCKXHU6AMIWDF78HOHVQMZBJ"',
23 silly registry.get     'x-served-by': 'cache-c48-CHI',
23 silly registry.get     'x-cache': 'MISS',
23 silly registry.get     'x-cache-hits': '0',
23 silly registry.get     'x-timer': 'S1395697324.748315096,VS0,VE121',
23 silly registry.get     vary: 'Accept',
23 silly registry.get     'content-length': '0',
23 silly registry.get     'keep-alive': 'timeout=10, max=50',
23 silly registry.get     connection: 'Keep-Alive' } ]
24 verbose etag learnyounode from cache
25 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'learnyounode', range: '*', hasData: true }
26 silly addNameRange versions [ 'learnyounode',
26 silly addNameRange   [ '0.0.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.0.9',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.1.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.9',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.10',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.11',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.12',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.13',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.14',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.15',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.16',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.2.16-mimbug',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.3.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.3.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.3.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.3.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.4.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.4.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-alpha01',
26 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0' ] ]
27 verbose addNamed [ 'learnyounode', '1.0.0' ]
28 verbose addNamed [ '1.0.0', '1.0.0' ]
29 silly lockFile 0820d686-learnyounode-1-0-0 learnyounode@1.0.0
30 verbose lock learnyounode@1.0.0 C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\0820d686-learnyounode-1-0-0.lock
31 silly lockFile 0820d686-learnyounode-1-0-0 learnyounode@1.0.0
32 silly lockFile 0820d686-learnyounode-1-0-0 learnyounode@1.0.0
33 silly lockFile a353de34-learnyounode learnyounode@
34 silly lockFile a353de34-learnyounode learnyounode@
35 silly resolved [ { name: 'learnyounode',
35 silly resolved     version: '1.0.0',
35 silly resolved     description: 'Learn You The Node.js For Much Win! An intro to Node.js via a set of self-guided workshops.',
35 silly resolved     author:
35 silly resolved      { name: 'Rod Vagg',
35 silly resolved        email: 'rod@vagg.org',
35 silly resolved        url: 'https://github.com/rvagg' },
35 silly resolved     contributors: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
35 silly resolved     repository:
35 silly resolved      { type: 'git',
35 silly resolved        url: 'https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode.git' },
35 silly resolved     license: 'MIT',
35 silly resolved     dependencies:
35 silly resolved      { workshopper: '^1.0.0-alpha05',
35 silly resolved        'workshopper-exercise': '^0.2.2',
35 silly resolved        'workshopper-wrappedexec': '^0.1.1',
35 silly resolved        'workshopper-boilerplate': '0.0.1',
35 silly resolved        'concat-stream': '^1.4.1',
35 silly resolved        duplexer: '^0.1.1',
35 silly resolved        through: '^2.3.4',
35 silly resolved        boganipsum: '^0.1.0',
35 silly resolved        hyperquest: '^0.2.0',
35 silly resolved        bl: '^0.7.0',
35 silly resolved        'through2-map': '^1.2.1',
35 silly resolved        'colors-tmpl': '^0.1.0',
35 silly resolved        after: '^0.8.1',
35 silly resolved        rimraf: '^2.2.6',
35 silly resolved        chalk: '^0.4.0',
35 silly resolved        through2: '^0.4.1' },
35 silly resolved     bin: { learnyounode: './learnyounode.js' },
35 silly resolved     preferGlobal: true,
35 silly resolved     readme: '# Learn You The Node.js For Much Win!\n\n**An intro to Node.js via a set of self-guided workshops.**\n\n[![NPM](https://nodei.co/npm/learnyounode.png?downloads=true&stars=true)](https://nodei.co/npm/learnyounode/) [![NPM](https://nodei.co/npm-dl/learnyounode.png?months=3)](https://nodei.co/npm/learnyounode/)\n\n![Learn You The Node.js For Much Win!](https://raw.github.com/rvagg/learnyounode/master/learnyounode.png)\n\n  1. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)\n  2. Run `sudo npm install learnyounode -g`\n  3. Run `learnyounode`\n  4. **.. profit!**\n\n<b><code>learnyounode</code></b> will run through a series of Node.js workshops. Starting at a basic *"HELLO WORLD"* and moving on to more advanced exercises about dealing with synchronous & asynchronous I/O, filesystem operations, TCP and HTTP networking, events and streams.\n\nOnce you have finished <b><code>learnyounode</code></b>, graduate to <b><code>[stream-adventure](https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure)</code></b> for a set of exercises that dig in to Node\'s streams.\n\n### Contributors\n\n<b><code>learnyounode</code></b> is proudly brought to you by the following hackers:\n\n<table><tbody>\n<tr><th align="left">Rod Vagg</th><td><a href="https://github.com/rvagg">GitHub/rvagg</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/rvagg">Twitter/@rvagg</a></td></tr>\n<tr><th align="left">Andrey Sidorov</th><td><a href="https://github.com/sidorares">GitHub/sidorares</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/sidorares">Twitter/@sidorares</a></td></tr>\n<tr><th align="left">Julián Duque</th><td><a href="https://github.com/julianduque">GitHub/julianduque</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/julian_duque">Twitter/@julian_duque</a></td></tr>\n<tr><th align="left">Lars-Magnus Skog</th><td><a href="https://github.com/ralphtheninja">GitHub/ralphtheninja</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/ralphtheninja">Twitter/@ralphtheninja</a></td></tr>\n<tr><th align="left">Tim Inman</th><td><a href="https://github.com/thehack">GitHub/thehack</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/timinman">Twitter/@timinman</a></td></tr>\n<tr><th align="left">Dan Flettre</th><td><a href="https://github.com/Flet">GitHub/Flet</a></td><td><a href="http://twitter.com/flettre">Twitter/@flettre</a></td></tr>\n</tbody></table>\n\n## License\n\n**learnyounode** is Copyright (c) 2013 Rod Vagg [@rvagg](https://twitter.com/rvagg) and licenced under the MIT licence. All rights not explicitly granted in the MIT license are reserved. See the included LICENSE file for more details.\n\n**learnyounode** builds on the excellent work by [@substack](https://github.com/substack) and [@maxogden](https://github.com/maxogden) who created **[stream-adventure](https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure)** which serves as the original foundation for **learnyounode**.\n',
35 silly resolved     readmeFilename: 'README.md',
35 silly resolved     bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode/issues' },
35 silly resolved     homepage: 'https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode',
35 silly resolved     _id: 'learnyounode@1.0.0',
35 silly resolved     _from: 'learnyounode@' } ]
36 info install learnyounode@1.0.0 into C:\Program Files\nodejs
37 info installOne learnyounode@1.0.0
38 info C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode unbuild
39 verbose tar unpack C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\learnyounode\1.0.0\package.tgz
40 silly lockFile 6248517b-nodejs-node-modules-learnyounode tar://C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode
41 verbose lock tar://C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\6248517b-nodejs-node-modules-learnyounode.lock
42 silly lockFile 09a6ffd0-e-learnyounode-1-0-0-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\learnyounode\1.0.0\package.tgz
43 verbose lock tar://C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\learnyounode\1.0.0\package.tgz C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\09a6ffd0-e-learnyounode-1-0-0-package-tgz.lock
44 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
45 error Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode'
45 error  { [Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode']
45 error   errno: 50,
45 error   code: 'EPERM',
45 error   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\learnyounode',
45 error   fstream_type: 'Directory',
45 error   fstream_path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\learnyounode',
45 error   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
45 error   fstream_stack:
45 error    [ 'C:\\Users\\Tierney\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\fstream\\lib\\dir-writer.js:36:23',
45 error      'C:\\Users\\Tierney\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\mkdirp\\index.js:37:53',
45 error      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
46 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
47 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
48 error command "node" "C:\\Users\\Tierney\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "learnyounode" "-g"
49 error cwd C:\Users\Tierney\node\learnyounode
50 error node -v v0.10.26
51 error npm -v 1.4.4
52 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode
53 error fstream_path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode
54 error fstream_type Directory
55 error fstream_class DirWriter
56 error code EPERM
57 error errno 50
58 error stack Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\learnyounode'
59 error fstream_stack C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\dir-writer.js:36:23
59 error fstream_stack C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:37:53
59 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
60 verbose exit [ 50, true ]
```

[image: console with errors]

Comment: Looks like a permissions error, try running as an administrator

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an icon shortcut to launch your command line, right click and choose "Run as Administrator" instead of double clicking, then run the command again.

The giveaway is the text "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator".